# How to use latest SBT

Tags: sbt

I have SBT 0.13.7. I am trying to use 0.13.8-SNAPSHOT on master.

I download the code, make a couple changes, and locally publish the org.scala-sbt/main/0.13.8-SNAPSHOT jar.

I have a project with build.properties `sbt.version=0.13.8-SNAPSHOT`.

When I start `sbt`, I see

```
[info] Loading global plugins from /home/paul/.sbt/0.13/plugins
[info] Updating {file:/home/paul/.sbt/0.13/plugins/}global-plugins...
[info] Resolving org.fusesource.jansi#jansi;1.4 ...
[info] downloading https://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-snapshots/org.scala-sbt/main/0.13.8-SNAPSHOT/jars/main.jar ...
[info]  [SUCCESSFUL ] org.scala-sbt#main;0.13.8-SNAPSHOT!main.jar (2860ms)
[info] Done updating.
[info] Loading project definition from /home/paul/Private/lucid/sbt-cache/project
[info] Updating {file:/home/paul/Private/lucid/sbt-cache/project/}sbt-cache-build...
[info] Resolving org.fusesource.jansi#jansi;1.4 ...
[info] Done updating.
```

How do I use the local version of SBT instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted in [CONTRIBUTING](https://github.com/sbt/sbt/blob/0.13/CONTRIBUTING.md#modifying-sbt), you might have to run `reboot full` to clean out your boot directory.

Comment: That link is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks.